# Gitkraken Pro, Github Student Pack

Tags: gitkraken

I have a problem, I want to get gitkraken pro from the github student pack. I have the little pro tag in Github which means that I have the student pack, but when I connect my github account to Gitkraken it doesn't work, I still have the FREE offer.